# Power Query to fetch values based on 2 criterias

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to create a query based on below requirement. So far I am able to do my query based on single criteria only. Your help would be much appreciated.

1) I have opened a target workbook where I want to fetch matching values for  it's two columns (temperature & density) from multiple workbooks saved in a particular folder. Here I am referring to New Query > From file > From Folder option.

2) So In my target work book I have Observed Density and Observed Temperature and now I want to extract volume and weight correction factors from a pool of mutilple workbooks picked in step 1 as mentioned above (all the workbooks in the desired folder not only have Observed Desnity and Observed Temperature but also columns contaning corresponding weight and volume correction factors in them)

That's it. Just want to know if this can be achieved using Power Query or VBA is a must do do get results? If so, any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I would finish building the Query using the From Folder option to turn the data from all the workbooks into a single dataset.  This query does not need to be loaded into an Excel table.

Then I would start a new query based on the 2 columns in your target workbook.  They will need to be in a table or named range.  In that query you can add a Merge step to match to rows in the From Folder query.  Then Expand the results to add the columns you need from the matching rows.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the motivation but this is where I get stuck. I just want to understand the right way of comparing both temperature and density in base (current) workbook with all the workbooks I have in my designated data source folder using New Query > From file > From Folder option. Again, if any workbook in my folder which has same temperature and density as it is in my base (current) workbook, then the query should pull all those rows for me from each of those Excel files. Does above make it more clear?

Comment: I would set up the first Merge on temp and density, and when expanding get the Source.Name column (the file name from the From Folder query). Then you can Merge again, matching on that column.  The 2nd Expand will give you all the roles from the matched file.